# How can I construct and pass an iterator of iterators?

Tags: rust

I am trying to grok Rust by implementing simple algorithms in it. I managed to make a generic `merge_sorted`, which ended up having the following signature:

```
fn merge_sorted<IL, ILL, I: Ord>(mut arrays: ILL) -> Vec<I>
where
    IL: Iterator<Item = I>,
    ILL: Iterator<Item = IL>,
{
    // ...
}
```

This seems to be compiling on its own. The signature makes sense to me, as the function consumes the top-level iterator, and all the iterators it returns too. However, I am unable to construct a valid value to pass to this function:

```
fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2];
    let vectors = vec![v1.iter()];
    merge_sorted(vectors.iter());
}
```

As expected, `vectors` in this sample has the type:

```
std::vec::Vec<std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>>
```

This is the error message I get:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>: std::iter::Iterator` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:58:5
   |
58 |     merge_sorted(vectors.iter());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>` is not an iterator; maybe try calling `.iter()` or a similar method
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>`
note: required by `merge_sorted`
```

Where does the `&` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vec::iter` *borrows* the items it contains, so you are iterating over borrowed iterators (`&std::slice::Iter`) that do not implement `Iterator`. To consume a vector in order to have the ownership of the items, you must call `Vec::into_iter`:

```
fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2];
    let vectors = vec![v1.iter()]; // You can use `into_iter` there to iterate over ints.
    merge_sorted(vectors.into_iter());
}
```

You can also require `IntoIterators` that can make easier the usage of your API:

```
fn merge_sorted<IterT, IterIterT, T: Ord>(mut arrays: IterIterT) -> Vec<T>
where
    IterT: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    IterIterT: IntoIterator<Item = IterT>,
{
    panic!();
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2];
    let vectors = vec![v1];
    merge_sorted(vectors);
}
```

Comment: BTW, any suggestions on how to best make an iterator of iterators for a number of constants? Going through `Vec` seems excessive.

Comment: @LOST You can write a macro, but there are no easier ways to do this AFAIK

Comment: If you change `merge_sorted` to accept `IntoIterator` rather than `Iterator`, this becomes: `let vectors = vec![&v1]; merge_sorted(vectors)`. (Or `v1` in place of `&v1` to iterate over values.) It's almost always better to use `IntoIterator` as a bound for arguments because all things that implement `Iterator` also implement `IntoIterator`.

Comment: @LOST There is a `merge` function in the `itertools` crate which you may find interesting, although it only merges two iterators, not an arbitrary number.

Comment: @trentcl I am really just practicing writing short snippets.